# How to pass radio button value with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to pass the value of the selected radio to another page

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="return" value="return" />
    <label for="return">Retour</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="oneway" value="oneway" checked />
<label for="oneway">Enkel</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group right">
<button type="submit" class="btn medium black">Bereken rit</button>
</div>
```

I use the post method in php, input type works with `value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>"`

but the radio buttons doesn't, how can I fix this?

And which one is better to pass data, PHP or Javascript?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear enough. What is wrong? What do you want to fix?

Comment: I just want to send the selected radiobutton to another page, if the user select oneway and submit the button he will send to another page and see wat he select.

Comment: Did you use a `<form>` tag somewhere? Is this the complete code? What does `$_POST['radio']` contain?

Comment: yes I use the <form> tag, $_POST['radio'] doesn't work because both options have the same name.

Comment: @Can they do, because that's how you know which are in the same group... Just like in the answer provided by Junius, which you said worked ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick'n dirty solution :**

```
<?php 
$checked=isset($_POST["radio"]) && $_POST["radio"]==="oneway"?"checked":""; 
?>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="oneway" value="oneway" <?php echo $checked;?> />
```

but actually you should separate logic from template using a template engine like smarty or twig or mustache or whatever...